# How to clip a series by its grid?

Tags: androidplot

I want to create an `XYPlot` such that the most left point and the most right point of all series, are clipped off.

So, let's say I want to plot the series described by the following arrays

```
    Number[] xs = new Number[]{-1, 50, 101};
    Number[] ys = new Number[]{10, 20, 20};
```

But I want to clip off the first point (-1,10) and the last point (101,20), how could I do it?

I tried to use the methods `setDomainBoundaries()` and `setRangeBoundaries()` but the series exceeds it's grid/plot area.

[image]

Comment: Can you include your full plot code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a custom implementation of XYSeries to do this.  Here's a example that should basically do what you want:

```
    class MyXYSeries implements XYSeries {

        Number[] xs = new Number[]{-1, 50, 101};
        Number[] ys = new Number[]{10, 20, 20};

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return xs.length - 1; // clip the trailing point
        }

        @Override
        public Number getX(int index) {
            // shift xy vals over one to clip the leading point
            return xs[index+1];
        }

        @Override
        public Number getY(int index) {
            // shift xy vals over one to clip the leading point
            return ys[index+1];
        }

        @Override
        public String getTitle() {
            return "your title";
        }
    }
```